# Merge two time periods into one period

Tags: c#, .net, oracle10g

I'm working with a HR-system, built with .NET and Oracle, in which we store:

- employment history in one table with start/stopdate, for example organization, job percent, costunit etc
- salary information in another table with start/stopdate, for example month salary, hour salary

Every time any attribute is changed in this table, we create a new row and set the stopdate of the previous period.

Typically, when we want to present if to the user, we only present a small selection of attributes from both tables - for example organization and month salary to see a historical development of an employees salary, and this is where it starts to be tough.

If we only join the tables, we get a row for each change, and if there has been no changes in organization/month salary but in other attributes, an ugly confusing list would be presented to the user - "why are there two rows" is a very relevant question to our support. "Dear user - it's because we store the data in to tables" is not a nice answer ;)

```
Data:

startdate   stopdate      organization jobpercent monthsalary
2011-01-01  2011-01-15    Sales        50         25000 
2011-01-16  2011-06-01    Sales        100        25000         
2011-06-02                Development  100        35000
```

```
Result when querying only for start/stop/organization monthsalary with no date merge

startdate   stopdate      organization monthsalary
2011-01-01  2011-01-15    Sales        25000 
2011-01-16  2011-06-01    Sales        25000         
2011-06-02                Development  35000
```

The problem is that we have to merge the period in which the selected attributes are equal - the from/to-date can be changed because other attributes that are not selected can be changed.

```
This is the result I want when querying only for start/stop/organization monthsalary. The first two rows are merged into one

startdate   stopdate      organization monthsalary
2011-01-01  2011-06-01    Sales        25000         
2011-06-02                Development  35000
```

We have solved this though a very complicated sql statement with poor performance.

Is there anyone out there who have solved a similar use case? Or has a suggestion of a approach?

Any help is highly appreciated!!

Best regards 
/Anders

Answer (score 0):

I do somehting similiar on my HR app, what i do is a:

```
select distinct salary, xxx fields and then group by for all the fields
```

But maybe with only the distinct salary will be enough. I must say im talking about sql server, i dont know about Oracle but i guess "distinct" is there too. ;-)

Comment: The dates (start/stop date) aren't distinct, so I will still get one row for each change. So the problem is how to merge the periods where there are no changes in my selected attributes.

Comment: The distinct is for the salary field no the star/stop dates. By the distinct and grouping by i did almost the same, except that what i get is rows with hours worked each day (ie. 30 rows a month with different departments, still i return one month like x user worked 50hrs on development and 30 on sales, new im almost sure you need the "group by").

Comment: The tricky part is to add or remove fields on the select and group by to get the number of rows you need. It took me a few hours... :-)

Answer (score 0):

Group by the `organization` and `monthsalary` as these don't change. You can then merge the periods by taking the minimum `startdate` and maximum `stopdate`. This is assuming there are no spaces between periods:

```
with USRDAT as
       (select to_date('01/Jan/2011') as STARTDATE, to_date('15/Jan/2011') as STOPDATE, 'Sales' as ORGANIZATION, 25000 as MONTHSALARY from dual
        union all
        select to_date('16/Jan/2011'), to_date('01/Jun/2011'), 'Sales', 25000 from dual
        union all
        select to_date('02/Jun/2011'), null, 'Development', 35000 from dual)
  select min(STARTDATE) as STARTDATE, max(STOPDATE) as STOPDATE, ORGANIZATION, MONTHSALARY
    from USRDAT
group by ORGANIZATION, MONTHSALARY
```

Comment: Beatiful! The assumption you used is fully applicable! The job history have no gaps within an employment. If a person is reemployed - the person get another employeeid! Thank you very much!